# Pade approximation of gaussian distribution to given precision

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

Apologies if the question is too elementary here.

For a certain computational application I need to approximate Gaussian distribution $e^{-x^2}$ with specific absolute precision (within $10^{-7}$ over $\mathbb{R}$), preferably with rational functions.

Alas, I'm not familiar with approximation theory. Google pointed me toward Pade approximation as the way to go. Alas, I still don't know how to derive Pade approximation for a given function, much less how to ensure the approximation would fit to the prescribed precision. Could you point me towards the relevant information?

EDIT:

Here is some background. For some engineering computations I need analytical expressions for certain integrals; in this particular case for $e^{-x^2} \operatorname{erf}(x+a)$, where $a$ is a parameter that changes throughout the computation. Mathematica was unable to provide an analytical expression of $\int e^{-x^2}\operatorname{erf}(x+a)\,dx$ and neither was I.

That caused me thinking how can I approximate well known functions such as $e^{-x^2}$ and $\operatorname{erf}(x+a)$ (and possibly a few others I may need) so that their products would be analytically integrable?

It's very well known that one can obtain an analytic expression for an integral of a rational function, and that products of rational functions are rational. Thus the idea: approximate the relevant functions with rational ones using Pade approximation and integrate the products of Pade approximations. That would basically replace the integral I want with an expression containing a bunch of rational functions and $\log$s and $\arctan$s.

I've got to tightly control the precision of the above approximations though to have the model perform as expected. Thus the question.

Comment: Do you need to compute the Gaussian probability density or the comulative desnity (integral of the pdf from $-\infty$ to $x$)  The former is trivial using an $\exp$ library function.  The second is actually somewhat of a challenge.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: edited the question with the reason why I need that.

Comment: You'd do well to explain exactly what integral you actually want to evaluate.  It seems unlikely that the strategy you're suggesting would be optimal.  Is it just $\int_{-\infty}^{c} e^{-x^2 }\mbox{erf}(x+a)dx$?

Comment: If all you need is the definite integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2)\,\text{erf}(x+a)\,dx$, it has the closed form $\sqrt{\pi}\, \text{erf}(a/\sqrt{2})$.  Mathematica does not know this, but it is 4.3.13 in Geller and Ng's paper at http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf.  You can prove it by expanding erf as an integral of $y$, and then changing variables with a 45-degree rotation of the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Things like that, but possibly with different values of $c$ in the kernel of $e^{-x^c-y^c}$. The case $c=2$, a.k.a. Gaussian distribution, is the one that led to the question and is the most useful for this application. However, the case $c=1.5$, a.k.a. Holtsmark distribution, is also very useful in that context.

Comment: @MattF.: Does indefinite integral has the closed form? I won't integrate to $\infty$.

Comment: Consider asking on [scicomp.se]: there are more experts there on actually computing stuff numerically, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone has already encountered this exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It would be worth looking at [Schraudolph's](http://nic.schraudolph.org/pubs/Schraudolph99.pdf) sneaky trick if performance is your aim.

Answer (score 0):

In general, approximation with least maximal error is possible with the [Remez Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm).

In your case I would suggest giving approximation with [Chebyshev rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_rational_functions) a try.